# Flutter release build fails from terminal

Tags: ios, flutter, release

I'm working to build my app for deployment to the app store.  When I try to build via the command line the build fails with a linker error.  If I try the same build within Xcode 10.2 directly via Product -> Archive the build completes successfully.  I'm using the last flutter version from the stable channel.

I've tried uninstalling Pods completely and restarting but this doesn't change the error.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

I've also tried removing all my Pods that have platform-specific code and it still won't build using the command below.

The command I'm using for the build is

`flutter build ios --release --no-codesign`

I later use Fastlane in the process to complete the build (sign and upload to the App Store)

The terminal build error is shown below

```
ld: framework not found App
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ld: framework not found App
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    error: the following command failed with exit code 1 but produced no further output
    Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dhbqkotqxaizmcalpjzdyswlcahi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner normal arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue have been [filed in GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32454) few years ago. And since then, one of the workaround is the one mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32454#issuecomment-491490738):

> I think I had the same issue, also getting this error: ld: framework
> not found App
>
> This is how I fixed it: I noticed that in the `project/ios/Flutter`
> folder, `App.framework` was missing. Not sure what caused this, but I'm
> sure I did't delete it on purpose. I copied it from a new Flutter
> project and it works fine now.

If you have the same case, you can do the same workaround.

Also, if you are using latest version of Flutter this should have been resolved by [this fix](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/51453).